# Puppet class orders break using defines

Tags: ruby, puppet, puppet-enterprise

I have a level of dependency in the order of modules being applied:

```
class build() {
    # define order
    Class['base'] -> Class['config'] -> Class['app'] -> Class['sso']

    class { 'base' : ... }
    class { 'config' : ... }
    # etc
}

class base::init.pp () {
    class { 'base::prereqs' : ... }
    class { 'base::worker' : 
        require => Class['base::prereqs']
        ... 
    }
}

# etc etc
```

The error occurs when `base::prereqs` has:

```
define base::prereqs::file () { ... }

class base::prereqs () {
    $files = [ 'file_name', ... ]
    base::prereqs::file { $files : }
}
```

The desired order is **base::init --> base::prereqs --> base::worker --> config::init --> config::prepreqs --> config::worker --> app::init ...**

However the actual order using a define becomes...

**base::init --> base::prereqs (except resources created in the define) --> config::init --> config::prereqs --> ... --> base:prepreqs (resources created by define) --> base::worker**

The ordering inside `base` is consistent but the level above in `order` does not seem to know that resources have been added inside of `prereqs` and considers `base` complete.

Any help?

*Puppet v3.6.2 (Puppet Enterprise 3.3.2)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering relationships do not transcend common class declaration using `include` or `class { 'title': }`.

The easiest way to go about this in your scenario is to [contain](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#using-contain) classes.

```
class base {
    contain base::prereqs
    contain base::worker
    Class['base::prereqs'] -> Class['base::worker']
}
```

Comment: Novice question, can variables still be passed with `contain`?

Comment: Yes, you can. `class ntp {
  # ...
  class { 'ntp::service':
    enable => true,
  }
  contain 'ntp::service'
  # ...
}`
https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_containment.html#containing-classes

Comment: @rjinski yes, but it´s preferable to rely on Hiera and automatic parameter lookup instead, anyway.